# Why does 3d Bounding Box &&& check return true when I use ST_3DMakeBox?

Tags: postgis, 3d, extents, comparison

I'm just wondering why this [`&&&`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_3DIntersects.html) is returning `true` when I use [`ST_3DMakeBox`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_3DMakeBox.html)?

```
SELECT ST_MakePoint(0,0,0) &&& ST_3DMakeBox(
  ST_MakePoint(-1,-1,-1),
  ST_MakePoint(1,1,-1)
);
```

When these `&&&` returns false

```
SELECT ST_MakePoint(0,0,0) &&& ST_3DMakeBox(
  ST_MakePoint(-1,-1,-1),
  ST_MakePoint(1,-1,-1)
);

SELECT ST_MakePoint(0,0,0) &&& ST_3DMakeBox(
  ST_MakePoint(-1,-1,-1),
  ST_MakePoint(-1,1,-1)
);
```

Going through the X-Y, I can see a non-intersection in those ranges makes the 3d-test return false. However, a non-intersection in Z, even with `&&&` is still returning true.

```
    postgis_full_version                                                                           
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 POSTGIS="2.2.2 r14797" GEOS="3.5.1-CAPI-1.9.1 r4246" PROJ="Rel. 4.9.2, 08 September 2015" GDAL="GDAL 2.1.2, released 2016/10/24" LIBXML="2.9.3" LIBJSON="0.12.1" RASTER
(1 row)
```

Just an Ubuntu 17.04 stock install.

Comment: You link to the manual of ST_3DIntersects but you might mean the nd_overlaps: https://postgis.net/docs/geometry_overlaps_nd.html  Do you have GDAL installed? I don't see this happening in my 2.4 build but I also have CGAL installed.

Comment: @tilt if `&&` is what I want in 2d ,why isn't `&&&` what I want in 3d?

Comment: @tilt updated with postgis full version

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're seeing this behavior because the `&&&` operator is defined between two `geometry` arguments, not between two `box3d` arguments (`BOX3D()` and `ST_3DMakeBox` return `box3d`).  In PostGIS 2.2 and earlier, the cast from `box3d` to `geometry` dropped the `Z` ordinate, causing (among other things) the odd behavior you're seeing here.  More details in the [relevant ticket](https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/ticket/3466).